# How to select a child from an UIElementCollection where a property = some value?

Tags: c#, linq, children, uielementcollection

I have a `UniformGrid` with a number of `Button`'s as `Children`. Each `Button` has a `Tag` with an ID, e.g. (dumbed down code):

```
MyUniformGrid.Children.Add(new Button {
    Margin  = new Thickness(5),
    Tag     = Query.GetUInt32("id"),
    Width   = 200
});
```

How can I select the child `Button` object with an ID of 87? (as a for instance)

Intellisense isn't popping up with the Linq methods when I type `MyUniformGrid.Children.` (after adding `using System.Linq;`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var MyButton = MyUniformGrid.Children.
               OfType<Button>().
               Single(Child => Child.Tag != null && Child.Tag == 87);
```

Linq can't be run directly on `MyUniformGrid.Children` since [`UIElementCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d23e49d6-d96f-424f-8c90-92e0783e717f/why-does-linq-not-work-directly-against-uielementcollection?forum=wpf). Therefore `OfType<Button>` is required.